# Transfer function and gain at \$\omega_0\$ in unusual op amp bandpass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, active-filter, band-pass

The circuit diagram looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffHJjT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is simplified equalizer diagram.

How do I find the gain at \$\omega_0\$ in symbolic form?

Where:

$$\omega_0 = \sqrt{\frac {R_3 + R_4 + R_5 + R_6}{C_1 C_2 ((R_1 + R_3) R_4 R_5 + (R_1 + R_3) R_4 R_6 + (R_3 + R_4) R_5 R_6)}}$$

And the transfer function has this form:

$$H(s) = \frac{s^2 + a_1 s +\omega_0^2}{s^2 + a_2 s +\omega_0^2}=$$

$$\small\frac{s^2 +\frac{(C_1 (R_1 + R_3 + R_5) (R_4 + R_6) + C_2 (R_3 + R_4) (R_5 + R_6))}{C_1 C_2 ((R_1 + R_3) R_4 R_5 + (R_1 + R_3) R_4 R_6 + (R_3 + R_4) R_5 R_6)}s + \frac{R_3 + R_4 + R_5 + R_6}{C_1C_2((R_1+R_3)R_4R_5+(R_1+R_3)R_4R_6+(R_3+R_4)R_5R_6)} }{s^2 +\frac{(C_1 (R_3 + R_5) (R_2 + R_4 + R_6) + C_2 (R_3 + R_4) (R_5 + R_6))}{C_1 C_2 (R_3 (R_2 + R_4) R_5 + R_3 (R_2 + R_4) R_6 + (R_3 + R_4) R_5 R_6)}s + \frac{R_3 + R_4 + R_5 + R_6}{C_1 C_2 (R_3 (R_2 + R_4) R_5 + R_3 (R_2 + R_4) R_6 + (R_3 + R_4) R_5 R_6}}$$

if I did not make any error.

I did manage to find the voltage gain at \$\omega_0\$ by divide the "for order terms":

$$A_V(\omega_0) =
\small\frac{\frac{(C_1 (R_1 + R_3 + R_5) (R_4 + R_6) + C_2 (R_3 + R_4) (R_5 + R_6))}{C_1 C_2 ((R_1 + R_3) R_4 R_5 + (R_1 + R_3) R_4 R_6 + (R_3 + R_4) R_5 R_6)}}{\frac{(C_1 (R_3 + R_5) (R_2 + R_4 + R_6) + C_2 (R_3 + R_4) (R_5 + R_6))}{C_1 C_2 (R_3 (R_2 + R_4) R_5 + R_3 (R_2 + R_4) R_6 + (R_3 + R_4) R_5 R_6)}} = $$

$$A_V(\omega_0) = \frac{(C_1 (R_1 + R_3 + R_5) (R_4 + R_6) + C_2 (R_3 + R_4) (R_5 + R_6))}{C_1 (R_3 + R_5) (R_2 + R_4 + R_6) + C_2 (R_3 + R_4) (R_5 + R_6))} \approx \frac{(R_1 + R_3 + R_5) (R_4 + R_6) }{(R_3 + R_5) (R_2 + R_4 + R_6)} $$

Comment: If your TF is as you say it is then the gain = 1 for all frequencies.

Comment: @Andyaka see the example  https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/4112950600_1503855365.png

Comment: I don't need to see any example, I just note that you have corrected the error I pointed out. So next, what is preventing you finding the solution given that you have calculated W0?

Comment: H(s) doesn't appear to be in standard form. I would have expected to see \$ \omega_0^2\$ in the numerator and denominator polynomials.

Comment: @Chu I added full transfer function

Comment: Just substitute \$s\rightarrow j\omega_0\$ and solve for the gain.